# Source code search with Google Desktop

Tags: search-engine, code-search-engine, google-desktop-search

Is there a indexing plugin for GDS that allows for source code search?  I see some for specific types (Java, C++, ...) and one for "any text".  These are nice, but I would like one that allows for many/configurable extensions (HTML, CSS, JS, VB, C#, Java, Python, ...).  A huge bonus would be to allow for syntax highlighting (http://pygments.org/) in the cache.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just found Dropout and it seems to work great.  Put Dropout in any folder and it will index all files in that folder.  I put it in my Projects folder and it crawled all my code.  Very fast and flexible search.  [Dropout](http://dropout.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 3):

You could use [OpenGrok](http://opengrok.github.io/OpenGrok/) or some other code-specific search engine instead.

[I wrote a quick review](http://bugsquash.blogspot.com/2007/09/code-search-engines-mini-review.html) of some of them some time ago.

Answer (score 2):

It has been a long time, but the last time I tried to use Google Desktop Search for searching code, I found it quite inappropriate for that task, as I outlined at [http://perlmonks.org/?node_id=490310], the gist of which is that GDS (silently) only indexed a tiny fraction of many source code files (and made it quite a challenge to figure out why searching so often failed to find so much of what was in source code files).

I found Copernic Desktop Search worked better on code files (but I also had trouble with later versions of it being buggy in not finding all matches so I've been staying with version 2.1.1).  But these days I don't use it much (mostly because I don't have permission to install such things on the laptop provided by my new employer).

Comment: I found copernic to be awful at source code searching. I recently removed it.

Answer (score 2):

You can try out [Larry's Any Text File Indexer](http://desktop.google.com/plugins/i/indexitall.html).  You can specify a list of extensions at install time and it will do full text search on those file types.

Answer (score 0):

Im just giving this a go:

http://desktop.google.com/plugins/i/java.html?hl=en

..also you can search for things in your Java tree using the following syntax in Google Desktop:

```
<YOUR SEARCH> filetype:java under:"C:\hft\trunk"
```

..where I keep my code in "C:\hft\trunk"

Comment: Unfortunately, the link is no longer valid. Do you know a new link where this can be obtained from?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a Google Desktop plugin, but works for what we need.

We have started using http://svnquery.tigris.org/ and it seems to work and is very fast.  I wish it supported multiple repositories per site.  We have a repository per project, so currently I have to create a virtual directory for each project we have.  Not a show stopper, just something we need to automate in our project setup script.